# Subset dataframe such that all values in each row are less than a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe with a dimension column and 4 value columns. How can I subset the column such that all 4 columns for each record are less than a given x? I know I could do this manually using subset and specifying the condition for each column, but is there a way to do it using maybe an apply function?
Below is a sample dataframe.  For example let's say the x was 0.7.  In that case I would want to eliminate any rows where any column of that row is more than 0.7).

```
   zips ABC DEF GHI JKL
1     1 0.8 0.6 0.1 0.6
2     2 0.1 0.3 0.8 1.0
3     3 0.5 0.1 0.4 0.8
4     4 0.6 0.4 0.2 0.3
5     5 1.0 0.8 0.6 0.5
6     6 0.2 0.7 0.3 0.4
7     7 0.3 1.0 1.0 0.2
8     8 0.7 0.9 0.5 0.1
9     9 0.9 0.5 0.9 0.7
10   10 0.4 0.2 0.7 0.9
```

The following function seemed to work, but could someone explain the logic here?

```
Variance_Percentile[!rowSums(Variance_Percentile[-1] > 0.7), ]
  zips ABC DEF GHI JKL
4    4 0.6 0.4 0.2 0.3
6    6 0.2 0.7 0.3 0.4
```

Comment: I think this would subset the dataframe and only keep rows whose sum of columns is less than 0.7.  I wouldn't want to go far.  I'd want to keep all rows where all columns are less than 0.7

Comment: Please show what the result would be from the example data

Comment: Hm that did work?  Can you explain what's going on here?  I thought rowSums would sum up each row?

Comment: Just added what it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the negated `rowSums()` for the subset

```
df[!rowSums(df[-1] > 0.7), ]
#   zips ABC DEF GHI JKL
# 4    4 0.6 0.4 0.2 0.3
# 6    6 0.2 0.7 0.3 0.4
```

- `df[-1] > 0.7` gives us a logical matrix telling us which `df[-1]` are greater than 0.7
- `rowSums()` sums across those rows (each TRUE value is equal to 1, FALSE is zero)
- `!` converts those values to logical and negates them, so that we get any row sums which are zero (FALSE) and turn them into TRUE.  In other words, if the `rowSums()` result is zero, we want those rows.
- we use that logical vector for the row subset

Another way to get the same logical vector would be to do

```
rowSums(df[-1] > 0.7) == 0
```